# Zend2 translation performance and turning it off

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am using translation module in Zend2 framework, or better said i plan to use it. Currently i am using only default language and in template i am using this code for translation:

```
<?php echo $this->translate("Text to translate") ?>
```

I am using translation based on arrays. At this time i don't want to use translation, but i've prepared everything so it can be added later, so i am worried about performance. This will send request to translate every sentance, so i keep the file that holds translated sentances empty so it can not find translation.

Will this affect much on performance and is there a way to turn off translation, without changing the templates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply overwrite the ZF2 translate view helper by your own helper and let it just return the translation key, skipping all the translation logic. Whenever you need to make you application multilangual you can simply drop your custom helper and use the ZF2 builtin helper again. This way you don't need to change any views/templates.

Your helper should look something like this:

```
namespace MyNamespace\I18n\View\Helper;

use Zend\I18n\Exception;

class Translate extends AbstractTranslatorHelper
{
    public function __invoke($message, $textDomain = null, $locale = null)
    {
        return $message;
    }
}
```

Register you custom helper to the viewHelper PluginManager by implementing getViewHelperConfig method in your module.php.

```
class Module
{
    public function getViewHelperConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'invokables' => array(
                'translate' => 'MyNamespace\I18n\View\Helper\Translate'
            )
        );
    }
}
```